# Is it possible to prevent WiFi password brute-forcing?

Tags: wifi, brute-force

Are there any measures I can set, *except using a better password*, to prevent someone brute-forcing a WiFi password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Not using a Password would negate all brute forcing of the password...

But if you do I would recommend that you instead setup a Kerberos Network authentication setup with TLS certificates (and LDAP). But this would be a lot harder than just use a simple password exchange.